# How can I place three buttons in the same row at the left, middle and right in a fluid-width container?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I'm using `LESS` in a Twitter Bootstrap environment, but I'd accept straight `CSS` answers as well.

```
| Fluid-width container                            |
|                                                  |
| [Btn1]               [Btn2]               [Btn3] |
|                                                  |
```

Another width:

```
| Fluid-width container                |
|                                      |
| [Btn1]         [Btn2]         [Btn3] |
|                                      |
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion you can do this with a stock bootstrap environment like this:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span4 text-left"><a href="#" class="btn">Btn1</a></div>
  <div class="span4 text-center"><a href="#" class="btn">Btn2</a></div>
  <div class="span4 text-right"><a href="#" class="btn">Btn3</a></div>
</div>
```

This makes three `<div>`'s that span4 columns that make up the twelve column grid for bootstrap.

You don't need to add any extra CSS as those .text-left, right and center classes ship with bootstrap.

Comment: I didn't know about `text-left`, `text-center`, `text-right`.  Thanks! Why anchors instead of buttons?  And why `text-left` on the anchor instead of the wrapping div?

Comment: I did the .text-left just to show that it's available... It works with `<button>` and other inline elements. You are right about the class miss applied on the `<a>` instead of the parent element. So I just edited my response.

Answer (score 4):

I reckon this might be the simplest way...

### HTML

Note that the nested elements are `inline` elements

```
<div>
    <span>item1</span>
    <span>item2</span>
    <span>item3</span>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
div
{
    border: 1px solid lime;
    text-align: center;
}

span
{
    background-color: #ff8;
}

span:first-child
{
    background-color: #f8f;
    float: left;
}

span:last-child
{
    background-color: #8ff;
    float: right;
}
```

### JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/TUwek/

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/GNPpX/1/

You can do this using floats

```
<div class='container'>
    <button id="btn1">one</button>
    <button id="btn2">two</button>
    <button id="btn3">three</button>
</div>


.container{
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    border: solid 1px blue;
    text-align: center;
}
.container button{
    display: inline-block;
}
#btn1{
    float:left;
}
#btn3{
    float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is exactly what you want, but using `display: table;` on the parent and `display: table-cell` on the children gives you such a rendering :

HTML :

```
<ul>
    <li class="left"><button>BTN1</button></li>
    <li><button>BTN2</button></li>
    <li class="right"><button>BTN3</button></li>
</ul>
```

CSS :

```
ul {
    display: table;
    width: 60%;
}
li {
    display: table-cell;
}
li.left {text-align: left;}
li.right {text-align: right;}
```

**[The Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aMAxn/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work with the following:

```
<style>
    .center { text-align: center; }
    .right { text-align: right; }
</style>

<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span4"><button>One</button></div>
    <div class="span4 center"><button>Two</button></div>
    <div class="span4 right"><button>Three</button></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/feitla/yvXdc/1/

Here you go:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="container-fluid full-width">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <button class="btn pull-left">button 1</button>
            <button class="btn">button 2</button>
            <button class="btn pull-right">button 3</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.container {
   text-align:center;
} 
 button {
     display:inline-block;
}
```