# How to set 6 buttons in a column in Angular 6 using HTML

Tags: html, angular, typescript, button

I'm creating an application for airline tickets reservation.
In the part where client choose the place, I want to put 6 buttons in the row.  I'm using List to show all my buttons. Like on the picture, first 6 buttons have the correct position (red buttons). But blue buttons should be in the next row (like I show on the picture).How can I achieve this?

[image]

myplaces-list.component.html

```
<div class="inventory-body" >
 <h3 align="center">Wybierz miejsce</h3>
 <div *ngFor="let myplace of myplaces | async" style="width: 300px;">
 <myplace-details [myplace]='myplace'></myplace-details>
</div>
</div>
```

myplaces-list.component.ts

```
export class MyplacesListComponent implements OnInit {

myplaces: Observable<Myplace[]>;
place_id: number;

flight: Flight = new Flight();
submitted = false;
flight_id: number;

places: Observable<Place[]>;

constructor(private myplaceService: MyplaceService, private placeService: PlaceService, private flightService: FlightService,
          private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

ngOnInit() {
this.route.params.subscribe(params => { this.flight_id = params['flight_id']; });
this.flightService.getFlight(this.flight_id).subscribe(t => this.flight = t);
this.reloadData();
}

reloadData() {
this.myplaces = this.myplaceService.fetchEmpDeptDataInnerJoin(this.flight_id);
this.places = this.placeService.getPlacesList();
}}
```

myplace-details.component.html - My buttons are here

```
<div *ngIf="myplace" style="position: relative; left:-30%; margin-left:10px; margin-bottom:12px">
<div>
<a href="http://localhost:4200/ticket/{{myplace.flight_id}}/{{myplace.place_id}}"
 *ngIf='myplace.active' (click)='updateActive(false)' class="button btn-primary">{{myplace.location}}</a></div>

<span class="button btn-danger" *ngIf='!myplace.active' >{{myplace.location}}   </span>
```

myplace-details.component.ts

```
export class MyplaceDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

@Input() myplace: Myplace;

place_id: number;

constructor(private myplaceService: MyplaceService, private listComponent: MyplacesListComponent) { }

ngOnInit() {
this.place_id = this.myplace.place_id;
}

updateActive(isActive: boolean) {
this.myplaceService.updatePlace(this.place_id,
  { location: this.myplace.location, active: isActive })
  .subscribe(
    data => {
      console.log(data);
      this.myplace = data as Myplace;
    },
    error => console.log(error));
}}
```

Comment: Have Visit at the following I hope it would help you,
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17814009/10846431

Answer (score 2):

Rendering list in one container and styling it with just CSS is hard and tedious.

Plane layout provided has uneven spacing between rows (columns as it is rotated 90deg)
I'd consider replacing it or ditching it.

My solution is rather simple one: plane has two sides of seats (ABC, DEF) treat them as containers, space them adding ie. margin that creates aisle. In each container render all seats and using flexbox wrap them to new column. [Here is demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b9vdv2-md)

Other options:

- CSS grid https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/
  Render everything in one container and use grids / columns to shape it to your liking. (Don't know if allows uneven spacing)
- Table / div with `display:table` 
  Create table that covers whole plane and adjust cell sizes to match required dimensions. Use nth-child(n) on tr and td to style appropriate spacings. use multiple ng-containers in *ngFor to select where to put place-details components and where leave blanks for spacings.

Comment: Sorry, something didn't save properly. I've updated the link. Try again.